# Host connected to Cisco 3825 router cannot connect to the internet, nor can the router

Tags: networking, router

I currently have a Cisco 3825 router that I have (attempted) to configure. The router has two interfaces, GigabitEthernet0/0 and GigabitEthernet0/1. I would like Gi0/1 to act as my "WAN" interface while Gi0/0 acts as my "LAN" interface. The end goal is to connect the router directly to my Motorola modem, but for now, the WAN interface is connected to another router (a TP-Link TL-WR841N). The WAN interface is set up to receive a DHCP address from the router (similarly to how it would receive a DHCP address from my ISP), and is doing so successfully - the WAN interface has an IP address of 192.168.1.201 (TP-Link router is assigned the IP of 192.168.1.1).

The LAN interface of the Cisco router has an IP address of 10.0.0.1. I have a laptop connected to this interface that has a static IP of 10.0.0.2. The laptop is able to ping 10.0.0.1, but is not able to ping any external addresses (such as Google.com or 8.8.8.8). Furthermore, the Cisco router can ping the TP-Link router, but is not able to ping any external addresses either. This is my problem. My question is - how have I misconfigured the router and/or what am I missing?

I have posted the running configuration (which is the same as the startup configuration) below.

Thank you in advance!

```
Using 1285 out of 491512 bytes
!
version 12.3
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname CISCO3825
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 
enable password 
!
no aaa new-model
!    
resource policy
!
ip subnet-zero
ip cef
!
!
no ip dhcp use vrf connected
!
!
no ip ips deny-action ips-interface
!
no ftp-server write-enable
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no crypto isakmp ccm
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description Network-facing (LAN)
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.0.0.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 negotiation auto
 no mop enabled
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description ISP-facing (WAN)
 ip dhcp client client-id GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 negotiation auto
!
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/1
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip nat inside source list 10 interface GigabitEthernet0/1 overload
!
access-list 10 permit 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 password 
 login
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
!
end
```

Comment: If the Cisco router can ping the TP-Link router but not other devices connected to it, it sounds like the issue is in the TP-Link router. What error do you get when you try to ping 8.8.8.8?

Comment: The Cisco router is able to ping both the TP-Link router and any other devices connected to it. For example, I have a domain controller with a static IP of 192.168.1.60 connected to the TP-Link router, and the Cisco router is able to ping it without a problem. I should also mention that these other devices are able to connect to the Internet without a problem.

When I attempt to ping 8.8.8.8 from the Cisco router, all five packets fail without any specific error code.

Comment: I don't know that it's your issue, but access list 10 is missing. Can you paste the sequence in which you try to ping 8.8.8.8 and get failures?

Comment: You're correct, access list 10 is missing from this config. I added in 'access-list 10 permit 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255' to the running configuration, but that did not resolve the issue. I will edit the original post to reflect the running configuration. I'm not sure what you mean by the sequence in which I try to ping - are we talking about the message I receive when I ping from the router, or from the laptop behind the router?

Comment: The information the router gives you, for example, the source address of the pings it sends and whether it received any ICMP responses.

Comment: CISCO3825# ping 8.8.8.8

    Type escape sequence to abort.
    Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 8.8.8.8, timeout is 2 seconds:
    .....
    Success rate is 0 percent (0/5)

I'm assuming this is what you mean? It doesn't give me anything else. Is there a more robust ping command that IOS has?

Comment: Yeah. Just type `ping` and hit enter.

Comment: I've discovered what the issue is, and I've resolved it! When you asked for a bit more information on the pings, I did some Googling and found that you can turn on more detailed packet debugging by typing "debug ip packet detail". This allows you to see a lot more information about why a packet did not reach its destination. In my case, I was receiving an "Encapsulation Failed" error - doing some research on this made me discover that by changing "ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 gi0/1" to "ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1", both the router and my host are able to connect to the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by changing the `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/1` route to `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 dhcp`, which promptly allowed me to ping external IP addresses. I discovered this solution after enabling detailed packet debugging through the `debug ip packet detail` command, which showed me that when I attempted to ping 8.8.8.8, I was receiving an "Encapsulation Failed" error. A brief amount of research afterwards led to my discovery that I needed to change my route.

Answer (score 1):

Your interfaces are shutdown.

1. conf t
2. int g0/0
3. no shut
4. int g0/1
5. no shut

Comment: They are not actually shutdown, the config I posted appears to be the startup config, not the running config. In the running config, the interfaces are up/up. I will edit the original post to reflect this, apologies for the confusion. Also, I have resolved the issue, answer coming in a moment.